# Are groovy associative arrays thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, associative-array, concurrenthashmap

I am having a groovy script in which multiple threads tries to write to same associative map declared as :     def array = [:]. Is put and get a thread safe here?I did not find much info regarding this. If it is not then what can I use?Java concurrentHashMap?

Comment: I don't know about Groovy specifically but in Java if the class isn't explicitly labeled "thread safe" in some way then it isn't.  And that *IS* in the docs.

Comment: `[:]` is actually a LinkedHashMap. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html In javadoc you could find thread safe info and recommendations.

Comment: got it.thanks.then i am good to go.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are backed by `LinkedHashMap` and as long as `LinkedHashMap` remains unsynchronized, then, no, it is **not** thread-safe. So you'd need to use some class from `java.util.concurrent`, such as a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, each with advantages and disadvantages.

In my case, unfortunately, it seems that our Jenkins admins disallow access to `java.util.concurrent`, maybe out of fear of a badly coded job taking up too many resources from the server. For my use case, I am what you might call SOOL.